# Check if payment has been done in paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal

how to check in asp.net, if a payment has been done in paypal

So here the scenario:
I have an auction website 
the buyer bid on a product and win the product  from a seller(not me, it can be seller from different country),
the buyer need to buy the product now, i have redirected it to paypal,
 how would i check if the payment has been done and save it to my database

Hope i can get a help from you here

Comment: ... PayPal redirects back to you with information about the payment. Probably be good to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

paypal API returns sucess or failure status when it returns.

when you redirect to paypal for payment send these parameters too
return="successurl" and cancel_return="cancelurl"

if your payment is not made it will automatically send back to your cancelurl else to your successurl on your site.

hope this will help you. mark as answer if it helped. thanks